# Get random object with MongoDB on click

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm learning Node, Express and MongoDB and I'm trying to make a simple app that changes the image URL stored in my DB every time that I press the skip button.

The problem is how to pass the random number to the ejs side to communicate with the DB. Do I need Ajax to do this?

```
$("#img").click(function() {

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1  ;
  $("#img").attr("src","<%=image[random].url%>");  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Print your array on js, then use standard javascript

```
 var urls = [
   <% for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) { %>
      <% if(i != 0) { %>
         ,
      <% } %>
      "<%- image[i].url %>"
   <% } %>
 ];

$("#img").click(function(){

 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1  ;
 $("#img").attr("src", urls[random]);  

 });
```

Comment: I tried but it only changes on the first click, after that the random number stays the same